# How to pass text box value to javascript variable in asp.net mvc5?

Tags: javascript, asp.net

Hello all !

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <div class="tt-container">
        <input id="addres" name="addr" data-rulevalidAddress="true" 
        type="text" value="" class="form-control">
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var vm = {
        Address: document.getElementById("addres").value,
        MovieIds: []
        };
        });
        </script>
```

This doesn't yield Address value what i need to get through user input.
while :

```
        <div class="form-group">
        <label>Address</label>
        <div class="tt-container">
        <input id="addres" name="addr" data-rule-validAddress="true" 
        type="text" value="ABC" class="form-control">
        </div>
        </div>
        <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
        var vm = {
        Address: document.getElementById("addres").value,
        MovieIds: []
        };
        });
        </script>
```

this is working.

Kindly help me, i need user input to get referenced.

For understanding, some controller code is here :

```
        var rental = new Rentals
        {
        customers = customer,
        movies = movies,
        E_mail = User.Identity.GetUserName(),
        Address = rentalDto.Address,
        PhoneNumber = rentalDto.Phone,
        Renting_Option = rentalDto.B_option,
        DateRented = DateTime.Now
        };
```

Comment: You are putting the value of the input into the `vm.Address` object as soon ad the DOM is ready. In your first example there is an empty string as the value in the second example you have the value set as ABC. I assume you need some sort of user interaction before you set the `vm` object

Answer (score 0):

try

```
Address: $("#addres").val(),
```